# align suggestions of autocomplete extender with textbox

Tags: asp.net, autocompleteextender

I am using autocompleteextender in asp.net. When i type keyword, the suggestions i get are not align with the textbox. I want it to be align with my textbox. How can i do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try fiddling with the css, maybe go into the -'s on left to get it accross, otherwise i recommend [Jquery](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)